# Capture all messages send to p:growl

Tags: primefaces

Primefaces 13.0.2

You know, always the customer.

I have a CRUD view, everything is working fine.

- I have a p:growl
- Bean validation errors are shown
- DB contraints errors are shown
- Messages created by the application are shown.
- ....

Inattentive users say:

- Yes, there was a message, but I can't read
- Yes, I havn't read
- ....

I know, `p:growl` can be set to show the message longer and/or you must close.
But some user will also complain.

I'm looking for a way to offer the user a extra view, where the last messages can be shown.
So the user can have a look later, when he/she was to slow to read etc.

So I want to capture all the message, displayed by my `p:growl` element in the view.

I try to use `<p:growl binding="#{growlMessages.growl}" .../>`
and use `FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getMessage<*>` methods, but I can get ALL messages.

I get some messages (e.g: from my login procedure, where I send "Welcome" to the growl).
But I can't get contraints or bean validation errors.

Any idea how to "capture" all messages?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could create a PhaseListener to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following solution after getting the hint.

faces-config.xml

```
...
  <lifecycle>
    <phase-listener>myPkg.AppPhaseListener</phase-listener>
  </lifecycle>
...
```

AppPhaseListener

```
public class AppPhaseListener implements PhaseListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5974057200472814047L;

    @Inject
    private GrowlMessages growlMessages;

    @Override
    public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {
    }

    @Override
    public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {
        if (growlMessages != null) {
            FacesContext context = event.getFacesContext();
            for (Iterator<String> iterator = context.getClientIdsWithMessages(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                String clientId = iterator.next();
                for (Iterator<FacesMessage> messageIter = context.getMessages(clientId); messageIter.hasNext();) {
                    FacesMessage message = messageIter.next();
                    growlMessages.add(clientId, message);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
        return PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE;
    }

}
```

`GrowlMessages` will capture the messages, put timestamp and offer to UI.
In UI, I have a `p:sidebar` with `p:datatable`, using `GrowlMessages`.
So fare, I see all FacesMessages are captured yet.